# How to serialize properties excluded from serialization in catel?

Tags: catel

In my modelbase, I have properties that are of type Color and of type Thickness. The serialization manager has noted that these properties are to be excluded from serialization. I'd like to provide a method to serialize these properties.

Is there a way I can register a method to serialize these properties, so the manager will not exclude them?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation:

1. [Specifying what gets serialized](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Specifying+what+gets+serialized)

Basically means that you can decorate any property, field, etc using the [IncludeInSerialization] attribute to get it included by the serialization engine.

2. [Customizing serialization](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Customizing+serialization)

Shows how to create a serializer modifier to allow to modify a value before serialization and after deserialization. This means you can convert a *Color* to a `string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}", c.A, c.R, c.G, c.B);`. When deserializing, you can easily parse this yourself and get the color back. This allows you the serialize anything.

Comment: I've tagged the Color property with [IncludeInSerialization], and I've created a SerializerModifier class that modifies the serialization of my model base class.
I'm still seeing the SerializationManager complain that the "Property 'Color' is not serializable, so will be excluded from the serialization".
I explored catel's source, and it's failing to serialize because ConvertDictionaryToListAndExcludeNonSerializableObjects is kicking the property out because it is not serializable. Perhaps it should check for the IncludeInSerialization flag and let it pass?

Comment: I think you are right. Please create a ticket here: http://www.catelproject.com/support/issue-tracker

Comment: I've created a ticket at this link: https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-550.